# How to assign bit-pattern Z'FEDCBA09' to a 32bit integer

Tags: fortran, gfortran

How can I assign the boz-literal-constant `Z'FEDCBA09'` or any other bit-pattern with the most-significant bit equal to 1 to an integer?

The standard states:

> **`INT(A[,KIND])`:** If `A` is a boz-literal-constant, the value of the result is the value whose bit sequence according to the model in 16.3 is the same as that of A as modified by padding or truncation according to 16.3.3. **The interpretation of a bit sequence whose most significant bit is 1 is processor dependent.**
>
> <sub>**source: [Fortran 2018 Standard](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)**</sub>

So the following assignments *might* fail (assume `integer` is default 32 bit):

```
program boz
   implicit none
   integer :: x1 = int(Z'FEDCBA09')
   integer :: x2 = int(Z'FFFFFFFF')
   integer :: x3
   data x3/Z'FFFFFFFF'/
end program
```

Using gfortran, this will only work when adding `-fno-range-check` but this introduces extra unwanted effects:

> **`-fno-range-check`**: Disable range checking on results of simplification of constant expressions during compilation. For example, GNU Fortran will give an error at compile time when simplifying `a = 1. / 0.` With this option, no error will be given and a will be assigned the value +Infinity. If an expression evaluates to a value outside of the relevant range of `[-HUGE():HUGE()]`, then the expression will be replaced by `-Inf` or `+Inf` as appropriate. **Similarly, `DATA i/Z'FFFFFFFF'/` will result in an integer overflow on most systems, but with `-fno-range-check` the value will "wrap around" and `i` will be initialized to `-1` instead.**
>
> <sub>**source: [GNU Compiler Collection, gfortran manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Fortran-Dialect-Options.html)**</sub>

I attempted the following, which works fine but still not 100%

```
integer(kind=INT32) :: x1 = transfer(real(Z'FEDCBA09',kind=REAL32),1_INT32)
integer(kind=INT32) :: x1 = transfer(real(Z'FFFFFFFF',kind=REAL32),1_INT32)
```

The latter case fails with gfortran as it complains that `Z'FFFFFFFF'` represents NaN.

Using `IOR(0,Z'FEDCBA09')` also fails as it converts the boz-literal using `INT`

**Question:** How can you robustly assign a bit pattern using a boz-literal-constant? That is to say, independent of the used compiler (GNU, SUN, PGI, NAG, ...).

**Answer:** The most robust answer is currently given by [Jim Rodes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/798346/jim-rhodes) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58308414/how-to-assign-bit-pattern-zfedcba09-to-a-32bit-integer#comment102981365_58308414):

```
x = ior(ishft(int(Z'FEDC'),bit_size(x)/2),int(Z'BA09'))
```

This will work on any compiler and does not require any other data-type to be successful.

Comment: Can you use the low 32 bits of a 64-bit integer?

Comment: @JimRhodes Please elaborate a bit? If you mean if I could delcare my integers as 64bit, the answer is no.

Comment: That is what I meant. So if you don't have 64bit integers, I guess it depends on what you what to do with these values.

Comment: @JimRhodes lets just say that I would like to create integers with that particular bit pattern in a way that works with most compilers. I do have access too `INT64`

Comment: This does, however, not answer the question of how you would do it if you do not have access to larger storage sized types.

Comment: That is why I asked what you need to do with these values. In Java there are no unsigned integers and so I sometimes have to deal with splitting an unsigned into 2 smaller signed types and manipulate the values as needed. For example, you could split **x1** into `x1Hi = int(Z'FEDC')` and `x1Lo = int(Z'BA09')`.

Comment: FWIW I have asked the same a few years ago at comp.lang.fortran. See https://in.memory.of.e.tern.al/comp.lang.fortran/thread/3878931

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with languages that do not support unsigned integers and you need to be able to test and/or set the high bit of the largest available integer, you can split the value into 2 variables and deal with the high order and low order bits separately.

One method would be to put the upper half into one variable and the lower half into another so that:

```
integer :: x1 = int(Z'FEDCBA09')
```

becomes:

```
integer :: x1Hi = int(Z'FEDC')
integer :: x1Lo = int(Z'BA09')
```

As the OP pointed out in an edit, a shift operation could then be used to assign the full value to a single variable like this. I changed it slightly so that it would work in case `x` is more than 32 bits.

```
x = ior(ishft(int(Z'FEDC'), 16), int(Z'BA09'))
```

Another possible method would be to have a separate variable for just the high bit.

Comment: But there is still the problem how to set the final value in the single final variable. Of course it is doable but may not be clear to everyone.

Comment: To be clear. My previous comment addressed the first part of the answer. For the other half I would recommend just to use 4 and not `bit_size(x)/2` because that is what one actually wants and one day `x` might get promoted to 16 bytes and a strange value will appear and the user might be clueless for a while.

Comment: @VladimirF, I agree. The actual bit count of the number of low order bits should be used for the shift which in this case is 16.

Comment: Sorry, 16. Maybe the cleanest is `int( ,int32)` and explicitly 16. May in case the `x` is promoted the bit pattern would not make sense anyway, but it just makes more sense.

Answer (score 6):

The need for `-fno-range-check` has been removed in what will be gfortran 10.1 when it is released.  In 10.1, the bit patterns you have specified will be treated as if they are 32-bit unsigned integers and twos-complement wrap-around semantics are enforced.

Your first code snippet with a `print` statement added

```
program boz
  implicit none
  integer :: x1 = int(Z'FEDCBA09')
  integer :: x2 = int(Z'FFFFFFFF')
  integer :: x3
  data x3/Z'FFFFFFFF'/
  print *, x1, x2, x3
end program
```

yields

```
$ gfortran -o z file.f90
$ ./z
-19088887  -1 -1
```

and does not require the `-fno-range-check` option. The same goes for the proposed `transfer` method:

```
program boz
   use iso_fortran_env
   implicit none
   integer(kind=INT32) :: x1 = &
   &   transfer(real(Z'FEDCBA09',kind=REAL32),1_INT32)
   integer(kind=INT32) :: x2 = &
   &   transfer(real(Z'FFFFFFFF',kind=REAL32),1_INT32)
   print '(I0,1X,Z8.8)', x1, x1
   print '(I0,1X,Z8.8)', x2, x2
end program
```

returning:

```
$ gfortran -o z file.f90
$ ./z
-19088887 FEDCBA09
2143289344 7FC00000
```

**Note:** gfortran converts `sNaN` into `qNan`, which is a bug but no one cares.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we do it if we do not have GNU fortran 10.1?

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck with an older version of gfortran, then with the
`integer` case you need to use an intermediate conversion

```
program boz
  use iso_fortran_env
  implicit none
  integer(kind=INT32) :: x1 = &
  & transfer(int(Z'FEDCBA09',kind=INT64),1_INT32)
  print '(I0,1X,Z8.8)', x1, x1
end program
```

gfortran will constant fold the statement with `transfer`.  You can verify this by looking at the file created with the -fdump-tree-original option.  For both this answer and the previous one, the command line is simple `gfortran -o z file.f90`.

Comment: Thanks. Please add this to the previous post by clicking on [edit] under the previous answer.

Comment: I assume you mean INT64 instead of REAL64

Comment: @kvantor, good catch.  Yes, I meant `INT64`.  (Un)Fortunately, `REAL64 == INT64`, so the code worked as intended.

Comment: True that `REAL64` and `INT64` are equal in gfortran and most compilers, but the standard does not state that these identifiers have to be equal.

Comment: The problem with this, as mentioned by yourself in https://in.memory.of.e.tern.al/comp.lang.fortran/thread/3878931 appears when setting an x-bit bit pattern if no higher integer kind is available.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked a similar question before at comp.lang.fortran: https://in.memory.of.e.tern.al/comp.lang.fortran/thread/3878931

A practically usable, even though still the 100% probability was still questioned by some (see there) was just to use the reverse BOZ constant/string and `NOT()` it.

Instead of

```
integer, parameter :: i = Z'A0000000'
```

use

```
integer, parameter :: i = NOT(int(Z'5FFFFFFF'))
```

The analysis in the link goes to a large detail and to fine points of the standard and the numeric model interpretation.

Since then I use this in my production code: https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/master/src/rng_par_zig.f90 line 285 which is a translation of http://vigna.di.unimi.it/xorshift/xorshift128plus.c

Comment: I think this is a great solution, but I got a case where `INTEGER` was "artificially" pimped to an `INT64` (`-fdefault-integer-8` in Gfortran). This solution did not create the boz `Z'A0000000` but `Z'FFFFFFFFA0000000`.

Comment: @kvantour It is hardly surprising, your question states that we should assume integers are 32 bits. And one usually uses bit patterns when one can assume certain number of bits, it is quite bold to assume the bits will be filled with some specific values. Numerically, `Z'A0000000` and `Z'FFFFFFFFA0000000`, or actually `int(Z'A0000000',int32) , int(Z'FFFFFFFFA0000000',int64)` are the same integer value.